# Display Custom User Fields in Profiles (Group ID)

Tags: solspace-user

We are using User 3.4.4. We want the Group_ID (Member Group) that is selected on the Register form to be displayed somewhere on the Profile (as a custom field?) Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, the `{member_group}` single variable will show the member group ID for the currently logged in user

#### Update

I would create a new member custom text field to capture this data on registration. So during the registration process, have this text field hidden and then with Javascript copy the value from the Member Group field to this hidden text field. Make sense?

#### Update 2

Updated Kristen's fiddle for demo purposes. Added comments and optimized the function a little bit. ID selector's are always faster. Thanks Kristen for creating that fiddle. Here is the [updated one](http://jsfiddle.net/2zGuL/1/)

Comment: I need some indication in the user profile (EE Control Panel) what Member Group the user assigned themselves...so that could be something like Group ID or Group Name. The problem is that we are getting users not being assigned to the proper Group ID for some reason, so we want to be able to look in the User Profile to see what they selected, if possible

Comment: Gotcha, just updated my answer

Comment: First, thank you very much for your help. That does make sense but I am not adept at JS. Is it something easy to code?

Comment: @DigitalDud Super easy to code with jQuery. [Here's a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/2zGuL/)